# Javascript: What equals undefined? Why doesn't myVar == undefined work?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code that's confusing me.

it's basically

```
var myVariable =  $("#someNameHere")[0];
if( ! myVariable == undefined ) {
    //functionality A
}else{
    //Error handling 
}
```

Someone complained that the functionality associated with 'Functionality A' was never actually happening...so I investigated and they were right.

Now, originally, it read

```
if( ! myVariable == "undefined" )
```

and I thought I'd found the issue. but regardless of whether I use `"undefined"` or `undefined`, 'functionality A' never gets called.

I debug through the code and I can see that every time, at run time, `myVariable` *is* defined and *does* have a value.

Undefined *is* undefined - no one has assigned a value to it accidentally.

I tried

```
 if( ! typeof myVariable == "undefined" )
```

and that worked... what gives?

I understand why this doesn't work:

```
if ( ! myVariable == "undefined" )
```

And I understand why this does work:

```
if ( ! typeof myVariable == "undefined" )
```

but I **don't** understand why this doesn't work:

```
if ( ! myVariable == undefined )
```

when `myVariable` has a value and `undefined` is actually undefined.

Can anyone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: It may be that javascript first does ! and then ==, but I don't know where to look to find that documentation of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `!== undefined`. `! myVariable == undefined` is parsed as `(!myVariable) == undefined` due to [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table), which is always `false` as `!` always returns a boolean value.

Comment: So ! myvariable == undefined turns into "false-y == undefined"... but would that still not resolve as true?

Comment: Ah, thought the fuzzy == worked a bit different than that, and two false-y values would be equal. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Dogbert, actually he should use `!==`, not `!=`

Comment: @Alnitak so !== is like === , and != is like == ?. Jesus JS equality operators are not as intuitive as one would expect them to be.

Comment: @Paul yes, that's right, but it's (mostly) perfectly intuitive - with `==` and `!=` the operands are cast to a common type, and then compared (just occasionally with surprising results).  With `===` and `!==` they must be _exactly_ the same type.  By default you should _always_ use `===` unless you specifically want the type coercion of `==`

Comment: @Paul: A table you might find interesting: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: @Dogbert nice link :)   ps please update your answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for :

```
if (typeof myVariable != "undefined")
```

`!myVariable` means take the truth value of variable and negate it.

Comment: there's no need for a `typeof` check in modern JS - comparing with the literal `undefined` is sufficient (and probably faster)

Comment: this code is technically correct - I don't think it merits a downvote

Comment: @Alnitak I'm a little sick of seeing `typeof variable === "undefined"` everywhere.

Comment: Thank you Alnitak for your support, I will take this on board

Comment: No worries Paul, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

`undefined` is "==" only with `undefined` and `null`.

You can read the algorithm [here](https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3).

Also `! myVar` will return `false` when `myVar` has a "truthy" value and therefore it won't be equal to `undefined` (keep in mind that `!` is "faster" than `==`, read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)). I think you meant `myVar != undefined`, though I would recommend using `!==` instead.